# Linaro android qemu screen unlocking

Tags: android, qemu, linaro

I have setup Linaro android with QEMU.
I referenced this document
    https://wiki.linaro.org/KenWerner/Sandbox/AndroidQEMU

As the document warns, it is really slow but seems working
however, when the boot process is completed, I can't unlock the screen.
I can move the mouse cursor, but I can't drag the Lock picture with my mouse.
is this because QEMU is too slow? or do I have to give the drag command
via some other way?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be [the official documentation](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/how-to-wake-up-machine) regarding this.  I also had luck (once) getting access to click the 'settings' icon.  Before it went into settings, it asked for my unlock code, then let me in.